# Python: help(numpy) causes segfault on exit

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-2.7, numpy, segmentation-fault

I came across a strange occurrence: in the python interpreter, I do the following:

```
>>>import numpy
>>>help(numpy)
```

The help displays correctly, but as soon as I press q to return to the interpreter:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I have no idea what causes the segfault and it still happens if I import numpy with a local name (the typical np). This does not happen with any other libraries. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling numpy but that made no difference. Is numpy too large to handle that way or is something wrong with my interpreter? How can I fix this?

I am running Ubuntu 13.04 32-bit and using Python 2.7.4.

UPDATE:
PYTHONSTARTUP and PYTHONPATH are both empty.
Writing a script which does this has exactly the same effect.

Also, numpy and other libraries work perfectly, it's just the help call that messes up when used on numpy.

UPDATE 2:

For test.py:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import numpy
    help(numpy)
```

Here is the gdb output:

```
$ gdb --args python test.py
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.5.91.20130417-cvs-ubuntu
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i686-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/python2.7...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /usr/bin/python2.7 test.py
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGPIPE, Broken pipe.
0xb7fdd424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
(gdb) where
#0  0xb7fdd424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0xb7eb2cf3 in write () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0xb7e447e1 in _IO_file_write () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#3  0xb7e446c6 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0xb7e45422 in _IO_file_xsputn () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#5  0xb7e3a025 in fwrite () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#6  0x080ac05b in ?? ()
#7  0x080b6bde in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#8  0x080b71c0 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#9  0x0811f939 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx ()
#10 0x080b80d4 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#11 0x080b71c0 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#12 0x0811f939 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx ()
#13 0x080b7265 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#14 0x080b71c0 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#15 0x0811f939 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx ()
#16 0x081203ee in ?? ()
#17 0x080e11f9 in ?? ()
#18 0x080e3daf in PyObject_Call ()
#19 0x08129483 in ?? ()
#20 0x080b8a3e in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#21 0x0811f939 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx ()
#22 0x0812029e in ?? ()
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#23 0x080e11f9 in ?? ()
#24 0x080e3daf in PyObject_Call ()
#25 0x0816dd88 in ?? ()
#26 0x080b7615 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#27 0x0811f939 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx ()
#28 0x081836c7 in PyEval_EvalCode ()
#29 0x08183b7d in ?? ()
#30 0x080a6032 in PyRun_FileExFlags ()
#31 0x080a65f8 in PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags ()
#32 0x080a74af in Py_Main ()
#33 0x080a7581 in main ()
(gdb)
```

Update 3:

The output of `$strace -f python test.py` is very long, here are the last few lines from where it clones a child process:

```
[pid  2610] clone(Process 2611 attached child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0xb7527968) = 2611
[pid  2610] wait4(-1, Process 2610 suspended
<unfinished ...>
[pid  2611] execve("/usr/bin/less", ["less"], [/* 53 vars */]) = 0
[pid  2611] brk(0)                      = 0x89ed000
[pid  2611] access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  2611] mmap2(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb7734000
[pid  2611] access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  2611] open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
[pid  2611] fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=93821, ...}) = 0
[pid  2611] mmap2(NULL, 93821, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xb771d000
[pid  2611] close(3)                    = 0
[pid  2611] access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  2611] open("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
[pid  2611] read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0\320W\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
[pid  2611] fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=121032, ...}) = 0
[pid  2611] mmap2(NULL, 124748, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb76fe000
[pid  2611] mmap2(0xb771a000, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1b) = 0xb771a000
[pid  2611] close(3)                    = 0
[pid  2611] access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  2611] open("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
[pid  2611] read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0\220\232\1\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
[pid  2611] fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1770984, ...}) = 0
[pid  2611] mmap2(NULL, 1780508, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb754b000
[pid  2611] mmap2(0xb76f8000, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1ad) = 0xb76f8000
[pid  2611] mmap2(0xb76fb000, 11036, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb76fb000
[pid  2611] close(3)                    = 0
[pid  2611] mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb754a000
[pid  2611] mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb7549000
[pid  2611] set_thread_area({entry_number:-1 -> 6, base_addr:0xb75496c0, limit:1048575, seg_32bit:1, contents:0, read_exec_only:0, limit_in_pages:1, seg_not_present:0, useable:1}) = 0
[pid  2611] mprotect(0xb76f8000, 8192, PROT_READ) = 0
[pid  2611] mprotect(0xb771a000, 8192, PROT_READ) = 0
[pid  2611] mprotect(0x8069000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
[pid  2611] mprotect(0xb7757000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
[pid  2611] munmap(0xb771d000, 93821)   = 0
[pid  2611] ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
[pid  2611] ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
[pid  2611] brk(0)                      = 0x89ed000
[pid  2611] brk(0x8a0e000)              = 0x8a0e000
[pid  2611] stat64("/home/marzul/.terminfo", 0xbfac7780) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  2611] stat64("/etc/terminfo", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
[pid  2611] access("/etc/terminfo/x/xterm", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  2611] stat64("/lib/terminfo", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
[pid  2611] access("/lib/terminfo/x/xterm", R_OK) = 0
[pid  2611] open("/lib/terminfo/x/xterm", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
[pid  2611] fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3315, ...}) = 0
[pid  2611] mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb7733000
[pid  2611] read(3, "\32\1)\0&\0\17\0\235\1Z\5xterm|xterm-debian|X"..., 4096) = 3315
[pid  2611] read(3, "", 4096)           = 0
[pid  2611] close(3)                    = 0
[pid  2611] munmap(0xb7733000, 4096)    = 0
[pid  2611] ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
[pid  2611] ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
[pid  2611] ioctl(1, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=24, ws_col=80, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
[pid  2611] ioctl(2, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=24, ws_col=80, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
[pid  2611] open("/usr/bin/.sysless", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  2611] open("/etc/sysless", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  2611] open("/home/marzul/.less", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  2611] open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
[pid  2611] fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=8748544, ...}) = 0
[pid  2611] mmap2(NULL, 2097152, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xb7349000
[pid  2611] mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0x5e1) = 0xb7733000
[pid  2611] close(3)                    = 0
[pid  2611] open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
[pid  2611] fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=8748544, ...}) = 0
[pid  2611] mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0x5d8) = 0xb7732000
[pid  2611] close(3)                    = 0
[pid  2611] open("/home/marzul/.lesshst", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
[pid  2611] fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=129, ...}) = 0
[pid  2611] mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) =     0xb7731000
[pid  2611] read(3, ".less-history-file:\n.search\n\"pus"..., 4096) = 129
[pid  2611] read(3, "", 4096)           = 0
[pid  2611] close(3)                    = 0
[pid  2611] munmap(0xb7731000, 4096)    = 0
[pid  2611] open("/dev/tty", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
[pid  2611] ioctl(3, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
[pid  2611] fsync(3)                    = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
[pid  2611] ioctl(3, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
[pid  2611] ioctl(3, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or TCSETSW, {B38400 opost isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
[pid  2611] ioctl(3, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
[pid  2611] rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x805cc00, [INT], SA_RESTART}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
[pid  2611] rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {0x805cb80, [TSTP], SA_RESTART}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
[pid  2611] rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, {0x805cbc0, [WINCH], SA_RESTART}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
[pid  2611] rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {SIG_IGN, [QUIT], SA_RESTART}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
[pid  2611] ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, 0xbfac9088) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
[pid  2611] stat64("-", 0xbfac90a0)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  2611] write(1, "\33[?1049h\33[?1h\33=\r", 16) = 19
[pid  2611] fsync(3)                    = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
[pid  2611] ioctl(3, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
[pid  2611] ioctl(3, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or TCSETSW, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
[pid  2611] ioctl(3, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
[pid  2611] exit_group(0)               = ?
Process 2610 resumed
Process 2611 detached
[pid  2610] <... wait4 resumed> [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 2611
[pid  2610] --- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
[pid  2610] sigreturn()                 = ? (mask now [])
[pid  2610] exit_group(0)               = ?
Process 2610 detached
<... write resumed> )                   = 73728
--- SIGPIPE (Broken pipe) @ 0 (0) ---
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
write(4, "l the attributes of the ndarray "..., 3043328) = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
--- SIGPIPE (Broken pipe) @ 0 (0) ---
--- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Update 4:

```
$echo $LESS

$cat cat ~/.less
cat: /home/user/.less: No such file or directory
```

Apparently less isn't configured at all.

Searching what didn't get cut off of strace in the terminal for "= 4" gave the following segments:

```
read(3, "---------\n    a, b : ndarray\n\n  "..., 4096) = 4096
read(3, "epstr = \", \"\n    arglist = argum"..., 4096) = 4096
read(3, "* Total of %d references found. "..., 4096) = 4096
read(3, "`output` not supplied then sourc"..., 4096) = 4096
read(3, "      r += sum([200 for w in wha"..., 4096) = 4096
read(3, "                  except NameErr"..., 4096) = 4096
read(3, "          return tuple([self.vis"..., 4096) = 4018
```

and

```
[pid  3294] write(2, "Missing filename (\"less --help\" "..., 42) = 42
```

Update 5:

```
$strace -f python test.py 2>&1 | tee -a out.txt ; (exit ${PIPESTATUS})
$cat out.txt | grep "open(.*) = 4"

open("/usr/lib/python2.7/site.pyc", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/traceback.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
open("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/easy-install.pth", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat.pth", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0-pysupport-compat.pth", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygtk.pth", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-support.pth", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools.pth", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client.pth", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client.pth", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel.pth", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol.pth", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx.pth", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope.interface-4.0.5-nspkg.pth", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/sitecustomize.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.pyc", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/aliases.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.pyc", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.pyc", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__config__.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/version.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/_import_tools.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/fft/__init__.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/polynomial/__init__.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/random/__init__.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/ctypeslib.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/ma/__init__.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/pkgutil.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/repr.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
```

Update 6:

Without `open(...)` I also found:

```
ERR_PRINT = 4
FPE_UNDERFLOW = 4
```

Comment: What if you write a script containing those statements and run it?  What does `echo $PYTHONSTARTUP` show?  What about `echo $PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: FWIW, I can't reproduce on python 2.7.3 and Ubuntu 10.04 (old school) and numpy 1.6.2

Comment: Now that you have a script to repro, do this: `gdb --args python yourScriptNameHere`.  Say "run" to start the program, wait for it to crash, then say "where" to see where.  Then post the stack trace for us.

Comment: OK, next step: run `strace -f python yourScriptName`.  See what the final function calls are before it dies.  You should see the `fwrite()` as in your stack trace near the end.  Show us what it says, which will include the file descriptor plus the first part of the bytes being written.  If you want to see more of the written bytes, strace has an option for that too I think.  This way we can discover whether it is crashing writing to stdout, stderr, something else, and maybe something about what it's trying to write.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Done, though I might have included too much, I'm not sure.

Comment: Does `echo $LESS` or `cat ~/.less` show you anything?  I'm curious if your "less" is configured strangely.  Also, can you run the strace again and search the entire thing for ` = 4` to find what file descriptor 4 is?  That's the one that gets written to before the whole thing comes crashing down.  Quite possibly it's the stdin of the spawned "less".

Comment: @JohnZwinck Edited question again. I think you put your finger right on the problem.

Comment: It's fine if your less is not configured in any special way.  What do you think the problem is now?  If you're still not sure (I'm not, to be honest), look again in the strace for the `open(` of the file matching the `write(4, "l the attribut...`.  You should somewhere see something like `open(...) = 4` which will show you which file was opened with file descriptor 4 (it might not say `open(` but some other call, just look for whatever returns ` = 4` with no extra numbers on the end).

Comment: @JohnZwinck I searched for `open(...) = 4` in the output, results are added to the question. I am certainly not well-versed enough to have any inkling as to what the problem is, I was just hoping that some obscure configuration might be at fault. I'll do another search that doesn't necessarily look for `open(...)` as well.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Found only two more lines, added them to question.

Comment: @JohnZwinck FWIW, I can reproduce this on a vanilla Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit. File descriptor 4 is created by a call to `pipe2(2)`: `pipe2([3, 4], O_CLOEXEC) = 0`, which is presumably a pipe between `python` and `less`. The call to `write(4, ...)` is happening after the `less` process has terminated, hence the `SIGPIPE`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Python side, I managed to track it down to this function in [`pydoc.py`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/pydoc.py)...

```
def pipepager(text, cmd):
    """Page through text by feeding it to another program."""
    pipe = os.popen(cmd, 'w')
    try:
        pipe.write(text)
        pipe.close()
    except IOError:
        pass # Ignore broken pipes caused by quitting the pager program.
```

...specifically the line `pipe.write(text)`.

The problem goes away if you change that function to...

```
def pipepager(text, cmd):
    """Page through text by feeding it to another program."""
    import subprocess
    pipe = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).stdin
    try:
        pipe.write(text)
        pipe.close()
    except IOError:
        pass # Ignore broken pipes caused by quitting the pager program.
```

...which might be a reasonable workaround, although I'm still investigating why that fixes the problem - there's very little difference between the `strace(1)` output for the two cases.

---

**Update**

Leeward has filed [a bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue18356) for this.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it for me. Please let me know if you find out why subprocess works as opposed to os for this case.

Comment: @Leeward It may not be a Python bug. I can't see anything obviously wrong with the underlying C code - it's just calling `popen(3)` and then dying in `fwrite(3)`, but the file descriptor and the buffer both look to be valid, so it may be a bug in glibc. When I installed debugging symbols, it looks almost identical to [another stack trace I found](https://retrace.fedoraproject.org/faf/reports/130148/). It seems to be consistently reproducible on Ubuntu 13.04, so it might be worth [filing as a bug report](http://bugs.python.org/).

Comment: I've filed a bug report as you suggested with a link to this question. Hopefully we find out why it breaks.

Comment: @Leeward Might be worth noting in the bug report that it (only?) occurs when using the Ubuntu packaged versions of Python and numpy. I have `python-2.7.4-0ubuntu1-amd64` and `python-numpy-1:1.7.1-1ubuntu1-amd64` (yours may be slightly different), in case it's just the package maintainer who screwed up the build somehow. I also tested with the debug packages `python-dbg` and `python-numpy-dbg`, which worked okay. I didn't try building Python from source.